# KendoUI Grid: Cannot intercept and cancel sort event if there are any pending changes

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Browser: IE 9

Context: An editable, sortable(server side) KendoUI grid is populated.

Issue:  The objective is to pop up a message if there are any unsaved changes.

- User clicks on a cell
- User edits the text in the cell
- User clicks on   the column header

The grid’s datasource does not catch the edit. Dirty property of the data item is false.
Kendo UI grid always sorts the column. I have been unable to find a way to intercept the sort event and warn the user and cancel the sort event.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a video demonstrating the [KendoUI Grid issue](http://youtu.be/thiUvwnxXkw)

Response from Telerik

Basically this is happening because when reordering the event that is used is the mousedown event. 
When the mousedown event is triggered the model is still not updated.

As a work-around I can suggest you the following resolution:

Put this in a script block after initializing the Grid. This way if the Grid is still in edit mode, no matter if you have made a change or not the Dragging will be prevented.

```
$(function () {
    var gr = $('#Grid').data().kendoGrid;
    gr.thead.on('mousedown', function (e) {
        if (gr.tbody.find('.k-edit-cell').length) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation()
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Add this `if ($(e.target).hasClass("k-link"))` inside the event to prevent getting click from everywhere else inside `thead` that isn't the metter area.

Answer (score 0):

Version: kendoui.aspnetmvc.2013.2.716

In order to cancel the sort event, call event.preventDefault() in the requestStart event of the datasource.

hasChanges() method of the datasource returns false if

- Grid columns are reorderable. (.Reorderable(r => r.Columns(true))
  //Kendo htmlhelper code)
- Sorting is done on the server
- User edits the text in a cell and click on the column header

If you remove the Reorderable setting, hasChanges() method of datasource returns true. 
Opening a support ticket for this issue.

In the meantime, if you would like to catch the edit with hasChanges() method when user edits the cell and clicks the column header do not set the Reorderable to true.